# When does StreamReader become null in C#?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I saw this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-6.0

The part of the code is:

```
if (!File.Exists(filename))
    throw new FileNotFoundException("The file does not exist.");

this.filename = filename;
string txt = String.Empty;
StreamReader sr = null;
try
{
    sr = new StreamReader(filename);
    txt = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
finally
{
    if (sr != null) sr.Dispose();
}
```

When does StreamReader become null?

Comment: I suppose if there's an exception in the `new StreamReader()` constructor

Comment: Try  StreamReader sr= new StreamReader(filename);   txt = sr.ReadToEnd();

Comment: @PawanLakhara - Why? What has that got to do with `sr` being `null`?

Comment: And, literally, `sr` becomes `null` when `StreamReader sr = null;` executes, but you mean "How can `sr` be `null` in the `finally` block?".

Comment: Note that in modern C# you could write that as `sr?.Dispose();` and either way you would be better with a `using` block, which does all this automatically

Comment: @Enigmativity - My question is: How can sr be null? In this code, if the file does not exist, we will not reach the finally block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code, it is first checked if the file exists, then a `StreamReader` is created which reads that file. By asking when can the `StreamReader` be null, you are asking when can it's constructor throw an exception. It can actually happen in several situations.

The constructor will throw an exception if:

- The process doesn't have read priviledges on the file OR someone else is currently using the file. After all, it was only checked that the file exists, but god knows if the OS will actually allow the process to read the file.
- The file doesn't exist during `StreamWriter` construction. Now I know what you're thinking: "But it just checked that the file exists". Yes, but consider this scenario:

1. it is checked that the file exists
2. (optional) it just so happens that after the check, the OS thread scheduler decides to suspend the running thread for some milliseconds to make room for other (possibly higher priority) threads
3. Some other thread, another process, or the user deletes the file
4. `StreamReader` constructor is called, and the file doesn't exist anymore

In summary, no amount of prior checking can 100% guarantee you will be able to read the file in the next nanosecond.

Answer (score 5):

I think your question is regarding the `null` check in the `finally` part.

The `StreamReader sr` variable may be `null` in the `finally` part, if an exception is raised during the execution of the constructor in `new StreamReader(filename)`.

Comment: My question is: How can sr be null? In this code, if the file does not exist, we will not reach the final block.